# App crash when getting push notification in flutter

Tags: flutter

am working with the "flutter local notifications" package and I made a todo app where I can create tasks and set reminders for them . everything works fine in the VM ,but ones I build the app and tested it in my phone (android not IOS) every time I get the notification the App crashes

the error message is:

> BlockquoteE/AndroidRuntime( 7541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541): Process: com.example.fixingtodoapp, PID: 7541
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3164)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:237)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:179)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:791)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver.onReceive(ScheduledNotificationReceiver.java:46)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3157)
> E/AndroidRuntime( 7541):    ... 8 more
> I/art     ( 7541): Enter while loop.

Comment: If you attach your phone to a debugger you probably will see, what error it is throwing ...

Comment: i  included the error message above i hope that gives u a hint about the problem

Answer (score -1):

i was not properly initialising the local notification object that's what caused the problem